# using Graphviz Dlls in asp.net c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphviz

I am using the Graphviz Dlls in an asp.net application, i am using the method described here to access the Dlls through my c# code:-

http://implicitoperator.com/blog/2010/4/11/graphviz-c-sample.html

http://implicitoperator.com/blog/2009/12/24/rendering-an-in-memory-graphviz-image-with-c.html

Everything works as i expect on my local machine while debugging and i get a pdf of my graph back.

The problem is when the application is deployed to our UAT server the graph isn't generated. No exceptions are thrown and there seem to be no errors at all i just get an empty PDF back instead of a PDF with a graph.

I have checked that the application has the correct permissions to call unmanaged code, i have checked the application can find the graphviz Dlls and i have checked that the dot code going into the method call is the same locally as it is on the server. Everything checks out fine.

i am tearing my hair out with this problem, anyone got any ideas what the problem could be ?

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but just in case: I had to include almost all dll's from the graphviz\bin directory to get the sample working, not only the ones mentioned by David Brown in the article (maybe due to the Graphviz installation folder not being in PATH). Still have some issues though ...

Comment: I am not familiar with the Graphviz Dlls, but do they create any files on the hard drive when generating the images? The .NET charting controls use a specific directory to create and destroy temporary files used in the dynamic chart creation process. When I moved a solution that used those controls from a development machine to a server I had a very similar problem. Had to give the IIS account privileges on the folder where the images were created by .NET.

Answer (score 1):

An idea to try: load the main Graphviz Dll in depends.exe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker.

may be you are a missing dependency.

Answer (score 1):

How are you registering the dll? Double check the web.config on the server perhaps (maybe you missed something there)?

Also like Justin C suggested, make sure there is not a temp folder on the server that the dll is using to stream write/create the PDFs into. You might need to allow write privileges to that folder etc.